# Why does foo{bar, baz} not expand to "foobar" and "foobaz"?

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files in my directory:

```
com.my.arsys.core.js
com.my.arsys.core-libs.js
```

Now I want to match these using globbing pattern (curly braces) and copy them to `a` folder so I run the following:

```
cp com.my.arsys.{core, core-libs}.js a
```

However I get the following errors:

```
cp: cannot stat 'core,': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'core-libs,': No such file or directory
```

I think the problem is with the syntax. Can anyone please help?

Comment: BTW, that isn't actually a glob pattern at all. Glob patterns only expand to files that exist; brace expansion gives you results whether the names given exist as files or not. If you were running, say, `{a,b}*.txt`, brace expansion would result in two results, `a*.txt` and `b*.txt`, and then each of these would be separately expanded as a glob.

Comment: ...this means that, given that `{a,b}*.txt` example, if you have `boo.txt` and nothing starting with an `a` and ending in `.txt`, you might get as results `a*.txt` and `boo.txt`: The glob that has a result would be expanded, the one that does not wouldn't. (If your shell's runtime configuration has options such as `failglob` or `nullglob` set, this behavior can be modified further).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks a lot for the clafication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra blank, try:

```
cp com.my.arsys.{core,core-libs}.js a
```

From bash man about **Brace Expansion**:

> A  correctly-formed  brace  expansion  must  contain  unquoted  opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression.  Any incorrectly  formed  brace  expansion  is left unchanged.